# php get string from array elements and concatenate into new array element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I am trying to return array strings based on position, concatenate and append into a new array.

```
$matches = ([0] => 20170623 004129 982 a [4] => 20170623 004130 982 b [8] => 
            20170623 004130 982 b)
foreach ($matches as $match){
    $arr2 = explode(" ", $match);
    echo $arr2[0] . $arr2[1] . $arr2[2];
```

The for loop works for explode and can see each element(strings) of the array being separated into a new array $arr2, but each pass through the loop overwrites $arr2. 
My echo is returning the same result (the result of the last pass) multiple times. Looks like once for each pass.

Expected output, maybe something like:

```
$arr3 = ([0] => 20170623004129982 [1] => 20170623004130982 [3] => 
            20170623004130982)
```

Comment: Could we maybe see some data, current output and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

In your case

```
<?php
    $arr2 = [];
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $values = explode(" ", $match);
        array_push($arr2, $values[0], $values[1], $values[2]);   
    }

    var_dump($arr2); // now $arr2 should contain all values
?>
```

Comment: it will push the whole arry, not the array values

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR thanks for comment! Updated the answer

Comment: add the index 1

Comment: it's ok, better run your code in fiddle with static data, and then answer here, it will helpful for others

Comment: This concatenates everything into a long array. So I get...
  [0]=>
  string(8) "20170623"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "004129"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "20170623"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "004129"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "982"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "20170623"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "004129"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "982"

See my expected results above:
$arr3 = ([0] => 20170623004129982 [1] => 20170623004130982 [3] => 
            20170623004130982)

Comment: array_push($arr2, $values[0] . $values[1] . $values[2]); does the trick

Comment: I accepted this as the answer for simplicity and for accuracy of expected results but please amend you answer with my above comment.

Comment: @Rthomas529 it's hard to imagine how your array data really looks as `$matches` as you wrote it in the question will be different. I would be ready to set up a demo but then need better data: see/try here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/baf35bf8c2e823f7d9c8127ae582855a85146ff7

Answer (score 1):

create an array above foreach, so it will not reinitialize with each iteration as, and add the values in it which each iteration

```
$arr=[];
foreach ($matches as $match){
    $arr2 = explode(" ", $match);
    array_push($arr,array_map(function($arr2){
         return $arr2;
    },$arr2));
    echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
}
```